# Сложение элементов из двух unordered_map

Tags: c++, map

Вообщем интересует возможно ли сделать это проще, с точки зрения количества итераций, чем сейчас (в данный момент не нравится использование вспомогательного контейнера)

условие: есть два unordered_map состоящих из объектов класса нужно  просуммировать(как пример) элементы с одинаковыми индексами в третий unordered_map, если элемент с индексом есть только в одном исходном контейнере, то просто продублировать его в выходном контейнере.

класс:

```
class A {
    public:
        int b, // первое свойство
            c; // второе свойство
    A ():A(0,0){};
    A (int b_, int c_): b(b_), c(c_) {};
    A (A &a1, A &a2) { // так реализовано сложение элементов
        b = a1.b + a2.b; // сумма первого свойства
        c = a1.c + a2.c; // сумма второго свойства
    };
};
```

контейнеры

```
unordered_map <int, A> X; //исходный контейнер 1
    X.emplace(1, A(1, 1));
    X.emplace(2, A(2, 1));
    X.emplace(3, A(3, 1));
unordered_map <int, A> Y; //исходный контейнер 2
    Y.emplace(2, A(2, 2));
    Y.emplace(3, A(3, 2));
    Y.emplace(5, A(4, 2));

unordered_map <int, A> Z; //выходной контейнер
```

текущая реализация:

```
{
    unordered_map <int, bool> tmp; // контейнер для ослеживания использованных элементов в Y 

    for_each(begin(X), end(X), [&Z,&Y,&tmp](pair<const int, A> n) {
        Z.emplace(n.first, A(n.second, Y[n.first]));
        tmp[n.first] = 1; // помечаем элемент
    });

    for_each(begin(Y), end(Y), [&Z,&tmp](pair<const int, A> n) {
        if ( !tmp[n.first] ) // если элемент еще не трогали
            Z.emplace(move(n));
    });
}
```

в результате должно получится нечто такое:

```
Z[1] b=1 c=1 // элемент из X
Z[2] b=4 c=3 // сумма из X и Y
Z[3] b=6 c=3 // сумма из X и Y
Z[5] b=4 c=2 // элемент из Y
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно, например, так написать.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

class A {
    public:
        int b, // первое свойство
            c; // второе свойство
    A ():A(0,0){};
    A (int b_, int c_): b(b_), c(c_) {};
    A ( const A &a1, const A &a2) { // так реализовано сложение элементов
        b = a1.b + a2.b; // сумма первого свойства
        c = a1.c + a2.c; // сумма второго свойства
    };
}; 

int main()
{
    std::unordered_map <int, A> X; //исходный контейнер 1
    X.emplace(1, A(1, 1));
    X.emplace(2, A(2, 1));
    X.emplace(3, A(3, 1));

    std::unordered_map <int, A> Y; //исходный контейнер 2
    Y.emplace(2, A(2, 2));
    Y.emplace(3, A(3, 2));
    Y.emplace(5, A(4, 2));

    std::unordered_map <int, A> Z( X );

    for ( const auto &p : Y ) Z[p.first] = { Z[p.first], p.second };

    for ( const auto &p : Z ) 
    {        
        std::cout << "Z[" << p.first << "] b=" << p.second.b << " c=" << p.second.c << std::endl;
    }        

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод на консоль:

```
Z[5] b=4 c=2
Z[1] b=1 c=1
Z[2] b=4 c=3
Z[3] b=6 c=3
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно добавить в A флаг об использовании, примерно так:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    int  a, b;
    bool used = false;

    A () : A(0,0)  {}
    A (int a, int b) : a(a), b(b)  {}
    A operator+ (A val) { return A (a+val.a, b+val.b); }
};

int main() {

    std::unordered_map <int, A> X;
    std::unordered_map <int, A> Y;
    std::unordered_map <int, A> Z;

    X[1] = A(1, 1); X[2] = A(2, 1); X[3] = A(3, 1);
    Y[2] = A(2, 2); Y[3] = A(3, 2); Y[5] = A(4, 2);

    // Проходим по всем элементам первого контейнера

    for (const auto &it : X) {

        auto key = it.first;
        auto v1  = it.second;

        if (Y.count (key) > 0) { // Если есть в обоих контейнерах ключ

            auto v2     = Y[key];
            Z[key]      = v1+v2; // Складываем
            Y[key].used = true;

        } else {

            Z[key] = v1; // Иначе дублируем значение

        }

    }

    // Проходим по неиспользуемым элементам второго контейнера
    // Остались только значени, которые необходимо продублировать

    for (const auto &it : Y) {

        auto key = it.first;
        auto val = it.second;

        if (!Y[key].used)
            Z[key] = val;

    }

    // Выводим на экран результат

    for (const auto &it : Z) {

        std::cout << "Z[" << it.first << "] : "
                  << it.second.a << "," << it.second.b << std::endl;

    }

    return 0;

}
```